# Evaluating an indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+2x+3}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the following integral 
>   \begin{equation}
> J = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+2x+3}}
> \end{equation}

I do not find suitable substitution to compute the above indefinite integral. Since $x^3+2x+3=(x+1)(x^2-x+3)$, substituting $z=\sqrt{x+1}$, we have $$J= 2\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^4-3z^2+5}}.$$ I think this is not a good substitution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it's possible in elementary functions?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It's not.

Comment: I do not have any idea.

Comment: @user149418 This integral does not have an indefinite solution as an elementary function. Where (or how) did you come across this problem ?

Comment: @Rebellos You are welcome to show us your proof of your statement.

Comment: it would be useful to mention how you realized that it does not have a solution in terms of elementary functions

Comment: I do not have any proper reference about this problem. One of my friend has asked to solve it.

Comment: [Solution involves the elliptic integral of first kind.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(1%2F(sqrt(x%5E3+%2B+2x+%2B+3))dx))

Comment: @Rebellos I don't think that it's elliptic integral in the  Jacobi's form. Also, WA can be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: As we say in jargon: "it stinks".

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: why would WA's answer be wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the integral is just a cubic raised to the power $-\frac12$ and the cubic has no repeated roots, it is not elementary but may be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals.

Suppose we want to find the integral from the pole at $-1$ to some number $y$ greater than that – the indefinite integral from $0$ follows from this easily. The cubic's factorisation as given in the question is $x^3+2x+3=(x+1)(x^2-x+3)=(x+1)((x-1/2)^2+11/4)$, so Byrd and Friedman 239.00 gives for this
$$\int_{-1}^y\frac1{\sqrt{x^3+2x+3}}\,dx=5^{-1/4}F\left(\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt5-1-y}{\sqrt5+1+y},m=\frac{10+3\sqrt5}{20}\right)$$